# Flutter app showing black screen in task manager in android physical device

Tags: flutter, dart

I have developed a few apps. But, in all those apps there is a common problem where when I go to the recents section in android it shows a black screen instead of the last state of the app.

[image: Bad state image]

When I press the recents button and click on my app it just crashes without any error and I have to reopen the app and it works fine.

All of the above problems don't seem to happen in the debug version of the app, only the release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i had the same issue.

After a little debugging sesión i think i found the issue in Android side. And i have a workaround.

I will report the issue to the flutter team.

The problem i when the MainActivity execute the onResume() callback in a short time and in certain circunstancies the screenshot is not ready to show and the os show a black screen because doesn't have the screenshot ready yet.

To avoid in the middle time i needed to override the onPause() callback into the MainActivity and add a delay into.

I am not recommend this solution in production ( but in the mind time can avoid the issue since the flutter team work in a fix from FlutterActivity )

You can add the override into MainActivity:

```
//Workaround to avoid error with screenshot in the task manager
override fun onPause() {
    Thread.sleep(100)
    super.onPause()
}
```

Let me know if this fix worked for you.

Here is the issue reported to the flutter team:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66288

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. So, what I found out was it was an issue only on my phone, on other phones it worked just fine. I tried your workaround and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[image]This happens when disable screen capture **disableScreenCapture()**. Verify and delete the following code if you use it on **MainActivity** inside **onCreate()** method.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

**[FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams)** *Window flag:* treat the content of the window as secure, preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.

It is a price to pay for the security of the application. I hope I've helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I know where I have to put this line of code?

Comment: Verify and delete the above code if you use it on MainActivity inside onCreate() method.

Comment: I checked the MainActivity file in my project. I don't seem to find the onCreate() method. Taking normal screenshots in the app works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your flutter version

Answer (score 0):

It may occur due to the flutter version. In my case after changing (downgrade) the flutter version it's working fine

Thanks.